# How to get the value from drop down box?

Tags: php, html, html-select

I want to know how to get the value from the drop down box and then paste this value in text box.
I am using HTML and PHP.

---

This is my code. I did what Lucanos did but it did not work.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <title>Num One Website</title>
    <? $con = mysql_connect( "localhost", "username", "password" );
       if ( !$con ) {
         die( 'Could not connect: ' . mysql_error() );
       }
       mysql_select_db( "dbname", $con );
       $result1 = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM Students" ) ;

       echo "<FORM>";
       echo "<select id='userid' name='userid' onchange='this.form.elements['showuserid'].value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value'>";

       while( $row1 = mysql_fetch_array( $result1 ) ) { 
         echo "<option value='".$row1['ID']."'>".$row1['ID']."</option>"; 
         $count = $count + 1;
       } 
       echo "</select>"; 
       echo "</FORM>";

       mysql_close( $con );
    ?>

    <form action="ConfirmEnter.php" method="post">
      <p>
        <input id="showuserid" name="showuserid" readonly="readonly" size=5/>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="text" name="mt" size=5 value="0.0"/>
        <input type="text" name="pr" size=5 value="0.0" />
        <input type="text" name="fi" size=5 value="0.0" />
        <input type="text" name="tot" size=5 />
      </p><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lucanos code doesnt work for you, because you place dropdown tag in separate form tag. It should be in same form as showiserid field.

Answer (score 2):

With simple javascript (no libraries):

```
<form>
<select id="userid" name="userid" onchange="this.form.elements['showuserid'].value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
    <option value="">Select a User</option>
    <option value="1">First User</option>
    <option value="9">Ninth User</option>
</select><br>
<input id="showuserid" name="showuserid" readonly="readonly">
</form>
```

With jQuery:

```
<form>
<select id="userid" name="userid">
    <option value="">Select a User</option>
    <option value="1">First User</option>
    <option value="9">Ninth User</option>
</select><br>
<input id="showuserid" name="showuserid" readonly="readonly">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#userid').change(function(){
    $('#showuserid').val( $(this).val() );
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The description is a bit vague, but I assume you're trying to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wp7dM/

The demo uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), a javascript framework I deeply recommend.